# dev_appserver: where do static routes get routed?

Tags: google-app-engine

Could anyone point to roughly where in the python sdk code static routes get loaded into or accessed by http_server. This is to debug a failure to load static images. In eclipse I can see the static routes loading into var appinfo from the yaml file, and later can see the dynamic routes being checked during a request, but having trouble following the in-between steps.
Thanks

Update 11/30

Previously tried variations on the yaml, path, etc that were suggested in some docs and postings.
Here is one of them. In this case there is no 404 error, but image doesn't load and Firebug reports "Failed to the load the given URL".

### app.yaml

```
application: crazywidget2  
version: 1  
runtime: python27  
api_version: 1  
threadsafe: false  

handlers:  
- url: /images  
  static_dir: /images  
  secure: always  

-url: /.*  
  script: crazywidget2.py  
  secure: always  

libraries:  
- name: jinja2    
  version: latest
```

---

### index.html

```
...  
<img src="/images/xyz.gif" alt="XYZ illustration" />  
...
```

### crazywidget2.py

```
...
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render({}))

...
...

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/script_send', ScriptSend),
                        ('/resetkey', ResetKey),
                        ('/admin', Admin),  
                        ('/start', Start),  
                        ('/', MainPage)],  
                            debug=True)  


 def main():

    app.run()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Update 12/3

Turns out that in the above case it works if the static_dir is relative, "images" instead of "/images". In the absolute case it tries to open that path as is. Maybe some other variations would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three relevant code pointers (all in [google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py)):

- [class FileDispatcher](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py#2028)
- [CreateURLMatcherFromMaps()](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py#3040)
- [DevAppServerRequestHandler._Dispatch()](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py#2704)

I would assume though, there are easier ways to debug your problem. If you would post your app.yaml and the path you access and the response you get, people here could start to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: does it work if you add a slash to the end of `/images` in your handlers? Try replacing `/images` with `/images/` in both places that you use it in `app.yaml`.

Comment: Tried it, but no help. I did find another change that works - make the static_dir path relative.

Comment: Ah right, sorry I missed that. It was probably trying to get to the `images` directory in the root of your hard drive, not in the root of the app.